# Visual Studio Addin - automated right mouse click

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, automation, add-in

Is there any way that I can make my addin press the right mouse button and then select one option from the opened context menu?

Something like this:

```
_applicationObject.Windows.Item(EnvDTE.Constants.vsWindowKindSolutionExplorer).Activate();
_applicationObject.ToolWindows.SolutionExplorer.GetItem(projectName).Select(vsUISelectionType.vsUISelectionTypeSelect);
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("PRESS RIGHT MOUSE BUTTON");
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("CLICK OPTION XPTO FROM CONTECT MENU");
```

Comment: Try to record a macro to do that then watch its generated source code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed @Adriano Repetti advice and found this out

```
_applicationObject.ExecuteCommand("ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.Rebuild");
```